# Manual & automatic validation losses are different

Tags: python-3.x, validation, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I use Tensorflow 1.14.0 and Keras 2.2.4. I am using the following code with a custom validation loss:

```
seedn=40
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seedn)
import random
random.seed(seedn)
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(seedn)

from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential

def EVM_cal(data,prediction):
    return np.sqrt(np.mean((prediction - data) ** 2) / np.mean(data ** 2))*100

def EVMper(data, prediction):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean((prediction-data) ** 2) / K.mean(data** 2)) * 100


x_train_s=np.reshape(np.arange(1,1201),(100,12))/18000;
x_test_s=np.reshape(np.arange(1201,1801),(50,12))/18000;

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8, input_shape=(x_train_s.shape[1],)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.add(Dense(x_train_s.shape[1],))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=EVMper)
fittingadam = model.fit(x_train_s, x_train_s, epochs=4,
                        validation_data=(x_test_s, x_test_s),verbose=2)

Val_Loss = np.array(fittingadam.history['val_loss'])
print('Last Val Loss (Automatic)= ', Val_Loss[-1])

myEVM = EVM_cal(x_test_s,  model.predict(x_test_s))
print('Last Val Loss (Manual) =', myEVM)
```

The output is:

```
Last Val Loss (Automatic)=  89.88273468017579
Last Val Loss (Manual) = 89.90268535029907
```

As we see, the manual and automatic validation losses are off about 0.02. Here, I have generated the test and train set as an example. But, for my real dataset, the manual and automatic validation losses are off about 2. Why they are different? How can I fix this?

Comment: It’s weird! I have no idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, but this might be a matter of batch size during evaluation. Different from usual losses, yours mixes values from many samples together. (The mean of two batches is not equal to result of the entire data)

You can try `batch_size=50` (the size of the entire test data) to test.

You can also try to call the Keras metric yourself in a little model like this (may also be affected by batch size):

```
dataInput = Input((x_train_s.shape[1],))
predInput = Input((x_train_s.shape[1],))
output = Lambda(lambda x: EVMper(x[0], x[1]))([dataInput, predInput])

evaluator = Model([dataInput, predInput], output)
print(evaluator.predict([x_test_s, x_test_s]))
```

If the issue happens to be batch size, one solution, only for losses that are samplewise (don't mix samples as yours seems to mix), may be to leave the batch dimension for Keras to handle (must test). Don't take the mean of the batch dimension, only the other dimensions. The final shape of the loss should be `(batch_size,)`.

Comment: On point! `fittingadam = model.fit(x_train_s, x_train_s, epochs=4, validation_data=(x_test_s, x_test_s),verbose=2,batch_size=50)` This did the job. Kudos!

Comment: Yes, the batch size was the issue. Does it mean at every epoch, the output validation loss is calculated over the last batch?

Comment: It's a mean of the batches of that epoch.

Comment: @Albert, if the answer is ok, please award the bounty. (It will not return to you anyway).

Comment: Sure. I gave it to you!

Comment: I don't understand your answer "It's a mean of the batches of that epoch. " At every epoch, it processes the whole dataset (all batches).

Comment: Yes, in your question there are two batches. It processes batch 1, gets metrics for batch 1. Then it processes batch 2, gets metrics for batch 2. Finally, it calculates the mean of the batch1 metrics and batch2 metrics. - `(metrics_batch_1 + metrics_batch_2)/2`.

Comment: But, the validation loss has to be calculated over the whole given test set after each epoch.

Comment: Keras does it by batches. If you want a whole metric you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The reason, I suspect, is because the `float32` is the default `float-type` in keras where are `float64` is default float-type in numpy.

My suggestion would be to try `cast_to_floatx`

Something like:

```
from keras import backend as K

def EVM_cal(data,prediction):
    pred = K.cast_to_floatx(prediction) # assuming they are numpy arrays
    data = K.cast_to_floatx(data)
    return np.sqrt(np.mean((pred - data) ** 2) / np.mean(data ** 2))*100
```

See this for clarification on `cast_to_floatx` : https://keras.io/backend/#backend

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I changed the code but it did not work. The same difference remained.

Comment: How about just plain `prediction = np.array(prediction, dtype=float32)`? Logically, argument is not that sound. But if this fails as well, I believe it is because the val_loss in history has been smoothed.

Comment: I just tried your second suggestion, prediction = np.array(prediction, dtype=float32). Again, they are different

Comment: Here, it is mentioned that the float is rounded off in Keras at `1e-7`
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11068

So you might have to round off your numpy computation accordingly. let me try and replicate the difference.

Comment: The difference seems just too big for being a matter of float32 vs float64.

Comment: @DanielMöller I completely agree. Assuming the Keras backend uses numpy in this case, the difference just doesnot add up.